# Collect data from user - weird interaction?

Tags: 2010, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm working on a workflow involving collecting data from users.  At the end of the workflow, it writes the data collected to certain fields in a custom list.  To test the workflow, I have 2 accounts, my regular account that I'm developing the site with (ACC1) and a dummy account with contribute permissions (ACC2).

I've encountered a weird interaction when assigning the task.  If my dummy account starts the workflow and assigns the task to my main account, the fields do not get properly updated at the end.  In every other configuration, it works as intended.

So,

- ACC1 assigns to ACC1  (works)
- ACC1 assigns to ACC2  (works)
- ACC2 assigns to ACC2  (works)
- ACC2 assigns to ACC1  (fails)

The text fields that are supposed to be updated are blank and the date is updated to 1/1/1900 for some reason.  I'm confused as to why this is happening as I want to avoid this when I release the site.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an [Impersonation Step](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428324(v=office.14).aspx#BKMK_UserStep).  If ACC2 does not have the ability to update the information in the custom list, this would alleviate that issue.

Comment: In the scenario that fails, it is ACC1 that is writing back to the custom list.  The task is assigned by ACC2 and completed by ACC1.  ACC1 has full-control permissions as well.